# expressjs file download memory leak

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, memory-leaks

I am getting a very strange behavior with ExpressJs the code below if hit by more than one request in a second throws 404 to the clients and looking at the logs all I see is the following:

> (node:1460) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11
>   file listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

target method (downloads a file from AWS S3 bucket and pipes the response) :

```
 exports.download = function (req, res) {
     var fileName = req.params.fileName;

     var options = {
         Bucket: config.s3.bucket,
         Key: fileName
     };

     res.attachment(fileName);
     s3.getObject(options).createReadStream().on('error', function(err){
         console.log(err);
     }).pipe(res);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable) was getting in the way. once I filtered it out from this request everything worked as expected.